# Reinitialising an array after creation

Tags: arrays

Out of pure interest, why do most programming languages not allow the programmer to reinitialise an array after it's creation.

#### Example

```
int apples[4][4]

apples[0][1] = "blue"

apples = apples[8][8] // Reinitialise the array with a new size of 8x8

apples[7][4] = "purple"
```

#### Explanation of what I mean

As you can see above, I create an array that is 4x4, then I assign a value, then I reinitialise that same array with a new size of 8x8, then I assign another value. In theory, I'd prefer that it destroy the contents of the old array (so my new 8x8 array doesn't have that value at 0x1).

However, I've searched high and low, yet I've not managed to find anything that explains why programming languages enforce this restriction. In my eyes it seems greatly beneficial to allow this and I can't see any immediate issues. But clearly there is an issue otherwise this would be allowed.

#### Question

So my question is: What's the reason that programming languages do not allow programmers to reinitialise an array after it's creation?

Comment: Slightly confused, if this belongs on the Programmers site then can a moderator move it. I apprantly can't move my own question and I'm not sure whether this should be on Stackoverflow or Programmers?

Answer (score 0):

Initialization can be done until code is not in running state, that's why initialization can  take place only one time in a code, for the second time if you are initializing same array, its already out of creation phase and now in running phase.

for better clarity size of array needs to be a constant at compile time because it might be getting used in code at somewhere.

```
int i=arr.lenght;
if(i<5)
{
//do something}
```

you can resize a dynamic array by `realloc()` in c and by using collection properties with `arrayList`, but its not re initialization.

Comment: So, you're saying it's because the array might be referenced somewhere else whilst it is being resized. Why can't this just return an error? Like: out of bounds?